# Getting id from from JSON objects inside onItemClickListener

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-json

First of all I use volley library for my post request. In this case I retrieve as response from the server the following json format.

```
{"status":"success","message":"Teams without a league have been   
 found.",
 "teams":[{"ID":"31","team_name":"A Team"},
          {"ID":"101","team_name":"The BEST team"},
          {"ID":"109","team_name":"ael fc"},
          {"ID":"110","team_name":"UK"},
          {"ID":"111","team_name":"cyprus"},              
          {"ID":"112","team_name":"biochemisty"}
          ]
}
```

I do all the necessaray JSON deserialization and dispay the objects of the team array in a list.

Now what I want to do is to store in a String array the ID values of the selected teams. Any ideas on that?

Here is the part of the code

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq1 = new  
JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_ALL_LEAGUE_TEAMS, jsonObject,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

                        try {

           if(response.getString("status").equals("success")){

           JSONArray teamsArray = response.getJSONArray("teams");


                       for(int i = 0; i< teamsArray.length(); i++){

                                 teams = teamsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                 noLeagueMembersClass = new 
                      NoLeagueMemberClass();              
              noLeagueMembersClass.
              setTeamMember(teams.getString("team_name"));

               noLeagueMembersClass.
              setTeamMember(teams.getString("ID"));                      
              noLeagueMemberList.add(noLeagueMembersClass);
                                 listView.setAdapter(noLeagueAdapter);

              listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                                 listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);

                                 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
              AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick
             (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You 
             clicked"+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                     }
                                 });
           }



          }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I try the following

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                                         try {

                                             final String teamId = 
                                             teams.getString("ID");
                                             Log.d("teamId",teamId);
                                         } catch (JSONException e) {
                                             e.printStackTrace();
                                         }

                                     }
```

but I always get teamId=120. For example when I select first row,I want teamId to be equals with 31. When I click the second row I want the teamId to be equal with 101 and so on. I don't want to pass any values to a next activity yet. I hope the following picture will get you to understand what I want to do.

[image]

In other words I want each click I do to correspond to the JSON table.

Comment: Didn't get the clear idea. You want to fetch id on selecting from listview or what???

Comment: I want to fetch the id of the team  on selecting from listview. It is shown json

Comment: Make a arraylist of NoLeagueMemberClass and then add object in that arraylist using for loop which you are doing.

Comment: I have  the ArrayList you are talking about. I think I have to do something in onItemClick method. But I don't know what. As I said I want to real team's id when I click a row of the listview. So something needs to be done there.

Answer (score 1):

{"DDL":[{"Id":1,"name":"Aruba"},{"Id":2,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"Id":3,"name":"Angola"},{"Id":4,"name":"Anguilla"},{"Id":5,"name":"Albania"},{"Id":6,"name":"Andorra"}]}

The above code shows the Json Array and DDL is the json array tag name.

//Country Spinner

```
private void getCountry(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"URL",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {



                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        countryarray = j.getJSONArray("DDL");

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getCountries(countryarray);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void getCountries(final JSONArray jsonArrayC){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array

    countrylist=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayC.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = jsonArrayC.getJSONObject(i);
          countryid= Integer.valueOf(json.getString("Id"));

            //Adding the name of the emtype to array list
            countrylist.add(json.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    countryspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddEmployee.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countrylist));


   countryspinner.setSelection(99);

    countryspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            countryid = (int) id + 1;
            getState((int) id + 1);


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This example will help you from the above problem

Comment: pls add a more detailed explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: what you are expecting?

Comment: do not only post code - explain why this solution work!

Comment: do yoy got it..first code is json array, and ddl is json tag name and using the belove code retrieve the id of which iem we are selected from spinner

Answer (score 0):

You can use list Activity and display all the data into it and after that

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){ 
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Can get more details from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html